# Why browsers have different colors?

Tags: css, colors

In my normal chrome and opera i have `background-color: #15a3e1;` https://abouts.co/color/15a3e1

and the same page in chrome dev, firefox and firefox dev i have a different color

[image]

UPDATE: I tested firefox, chrome dev and chrome on another computer and the colors is "blue" The correct one. this makes me confuse; why firefox, firefox dev, chrome dev shows different color and opera, chrome showing a correct color.

UPDATE 2: Tested all possible color options in flags and config, no luck and also reset a browser settings , no luck

[image]

Comment: This is most likely due to [screen calibration madness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPubgoqtfbk&t=1673s). Basically, the color correction profile is specific for each application.

Comment: Do you have any color profile configured?

Comment: @D.Pardal i have a default windows installed profile in my color management, thats all . in Nvidia settings its set to other applications control color settings, I tested firefox, chrome dev and chrome on another computer and the colors is "blue" The correct one. In my chrome://flags i have nothing special too. Where i can dig to change default color management for firefox and chrome dev ?

Comment: I don't know. Probably Chrome is applying color correction while Firefox is not.

Answer (score -2):

Chrome doesn't use color profiles by default, Firefox does (IIRC). You can tell Chrome to [activate the color profile](http://klyment.com/serendipity/archives/386-2010.05.17-Activating-Colour-Management-in-Google-Chrome.html) if you want. You can also try the nearest web-safe color. Also, if you're using a VM application, remote desktop, or any other viewer besides the native app then you might be getting a reduced color set, like 24bit instead of 32bit color.

or you can 
Try disabling "Color correct rendering" in chrome://flags